# Use mockito and junit to test images

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a method that gets as parameter a MultipartFile object. Inside the method I use `ImageIO.read(some_value)` and `ImageIO.write(some_value)`. I want to test this method with a mock image (I don't want to have images stored under the resource folder).

I've tried this:
`MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "boat.jpg", "image/jpeg", "content image".getBytes());` but without success.

```
public void f(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    final BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes()));
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        ImageIO.write(read, "jpg", baos);
    }
 }
```

When I run the test the `read` variable has `null` value. I think that problem come from `"content image".getBytes()`.

Is there a posibility to use mock images instead of real ones ?

Comment: You can't really test this method with mocks, as you are relying on successfully reading and writing images with ImageIO. You need to use a real image's bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"content image".getBytes()` returns a `byte[]` representation of the String `"content image"`. How is `ImageIO` supposed to construct a `BufferedImage` from that?

You have two options here.

1. **Pass a `byte[]` of real data to `MockMultipartFile`**

   - Since you mentioned you don't want to use mock image resources, this does not seem like a good fit.
2. **Mock `ImageIO`'s static methods using *Powermock***

   - The mocked method will return a real `BufferedImage` your method can use, without having to read an image from a file.
   - This gives you the added benefit of being able to mock the call to `write()` as well, if you wish.
   - Sample code:

```java
PowerMockito.mockStatic(ImageIO.class);

when(ImageIO.read(any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
    Object argument = invocation.getArguments()[0];
    // here you can check what arguments you were passed

    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(600, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); // create a BufferedImage object
    // here you can fill in some data so the image isn't blank

    return result;
});
```

Now, when your method under test calls `imageIO.read()`, it will receive the `BufferedImage` you construct in the lambda, without actually reading any files.

Comment: After spending some time to investigate it I created a random image exactly as you said above and works fine. Thanks for the response !

Comment: I know it is old, but when using this code I get the following error `The method read(File) is ambiguous for the type ImageIO`